# "Unexpected MATLAB operator" error when reading image

Tags: matlab, imread

I am trying to read an image in Matlab using the following command as I found it in Matlab docs:

```
A = imread(d:/img,png)
```

but the problem is Matlab can not read the path and says : `Error: Unexpected MATLAB operator.`

I also tried using, /, //, \ and \  in the filepath, but none of them worked.

Please let me know how to get it working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put `'` around the filename and the file is probably named `'img.png'` (a dot not a comma)

```
A = imread('d:/img.png')
```

Answer (score 1):

Also there is difference in the platforms:

- path on Microsoft® Windows® platforms:

  ```
  I = imread('c:/tools/goodstuff/img.png')
  ```
- path on UNIX® platforms:

  ```
  I = imread('/home/tools/goodstuff/img.png')
  ```